# Why is my class constructor returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, jestjs, tdd

I am learning Javascript classes and TDD currently and for some reason my class constructor is retuning undefined instead of a string. Have I missed something obvious?

Class:

```
class Passenger {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name
        this.bags = []
    }
    addBag(bag) {
        this.bags.push(bag)
    }
}
```

Test:

```
describe("passenger", () => {
    test("has a name", () => {
        const louis = new Passenger("Louis")
        expect(louis.name).toBe("Louis")
    })
})
```

Test Fail:

```
● passenger › has a name

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: "Louis"
    Received: undefined

      17 |     test("has a name", () => {
      18 |         const louis = new Passenger("Louis")
    > 19 |         expect(louis.name).toBe("Louis")
         |                            ^
      20 |     })
      21 | })

      at Object.<anonymous> (airport.test.js:19:28)
```

Comment: is the class corretly exported and imported in the test file?

Comment: module.exports = Bag, Passenger, Plane

Comment: const Bag = require("./airport")
const Passenger = require("./airport")
const Plane = require("./airport")

Comment: try to debug more in deep, like logging `louis`